# Formulate the Langrangian function of a non-linear optimization problem and solve it for $y\geq0$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Consider the (non-linear) optimization problem ($P$)

> $$max \quad3x_1 + 4x_2$$
>
> $$s.t. \quad x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 25$$
>
> $$ \quad x_1,x_2 \geq 0$$

Formulate the Lagrangian function $\varTheta(y)$ and solve it for fixed $y>0$

---

This is the function that I obtained.
$\varTheta(y)=25y_1 + max\{(3-y_1x_1)x_1 + (4-y_1x_2)x_2; \quad x_1,x_2\geq 0\}$

However, Since the coefficents in the $max$ function still have $x_i$'s in them, I am not sure how to proceed. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the objective function is increasing in the domain you just have to check the boundary an the problem reduces to
$$max_{x_1,x_2}\quad 3x_1+4x_2$$
$$s.t.\quad x_1^2+x_2^2=25$$
which has the Lagrangian
$$\varTheta(x_1,x_2,\lambda)=3x_1+4x_2-\lambda(x_1^2+x_2^2-25)$$
By applying first order conditions
$$\frac{\partial \varTheta}{\partial x_1}=3-2\lambda x_1=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \varTheta}{\partial x_2}=4-2\lambda x_2=0$$
$$\frac{\partial \varTheta}{\partial \lambda}=-x_1^2-x_2^2+25=0$$
which can be solved by $x_1=3$, $x_2=4$ and $\lambda=1/2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the problem had to be solved by first constructing a dual problem but that seems impossible. How stupid that I did not think of this. Thank you for your help :))!

Comment: You are welcome